# ffmpeg to calculate audio/visual difference between compressed and non-compressed video

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, compression

I'm trying to calculate the audio + visual difference between a harshly compressed video file and one that hasn't been.
I'm using pipes because ultimately I wish this to take src from a camera stream.

I've managed to get the video results that I'm looking for, but I'm struggling with the audio.
I've added a line to invert the phase of the compressed audio, so that when they add up in the blend they should almost cancel each other out, but that doesn't happen.

```
ffmpeg -i input.avi -f avi -c:v libxvid -qscale:v 30 -c:a wmav1 - | \
ffmpeg -i - -f avi -af "aeval='-val(0)':c=same" - | \
ffmpeg -i input.avi -i - -filter_complex "blend=all_mode=difference" -c:v libx264 -crf 18 -f avi - | \
ffplay -
```

I can still hear all the audio, when what I should be hearing are solely compression artifacts. thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To preface, I'm not sure your method would identify audio compression 'artifacts'

Your command doesn't perform any audio comparison, it only inverts a single channel. Also, the audio and video are compressed twice and the codecs the last ffmpeg command receives are the default AVI codecs of `mpeg4` and `mp3`.

Use

```
ffmpeg -i input.avi -f matroska -c:v libxvid -qscale:v 30 -c:a wmav1 - |\
ffmpeg -i input.avi -i - -filter_complex "[0][1]blend=all_mode=difference;[1]aselect=gt(n\,0),asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[1a];[0][1a]amerge,aeval=val(0)-val(1):c=mono" -c:v rawvideo -c:a pcm_s16le -f matroska - |\
ffplay -
```

I assume your audio is mono. If your audio has N channels, your aeval will need N expressions where the Mth expression is `val(M-1)-val(N+M-1)`

I also trim out the first encoded audio frame in order to mitigate encoder delay that Paul mentioned, and it seems to work here.

Answer (score 0):

There might be some delay introduced with encoded audio samples. Also your command is incorrect.